# How to wrap inno script inside Visual Studio and build automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, inno-setup

I want to include a inno setup script within a VS2015 project and build a installer with VS project build. The inno script should also be able to DDL's (resources) used in VS project.

Comment: You can easily write a post build event to trigger command line build of your Inno Setup script, but I rather use an external script to build them all, as you often don't want to wait for Visual Studio to build everything.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done those two methods. Just wanted to know if there is a plug-in or 3rd party extension for VS.

Comment: Yes, there is 3rd party extension Visual & Installer. See full answer below.